# AngularJS $watch is failing for arrays after 1st update

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I need to track when a model value which is an array has been updated by a directive but $watch appears to be failing.  I created a fiddle to illustrate the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/DsTLN/

I setup a watch so that I can perform actions when the model changes.

```
$scope.$watch('model.title', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  if ($scope.model) {
      console.debug("watchedTitle=" + newValue);
      $scope.watchedTitle = newValue ;            
  }});
```

If the model newValue is an integer, $watch fires consistently as shown in the debug logs:

```
watchedTitle=1 
watchedTitle=2 
watchedTitle=3 
watchedTitle=4 
watchedTitle=5
```

I setup a 2nd watch to monitor changes to the array:

```
$scope.$watch('model.titlearray', function(newValue, oldValue) {
```

If the newValue is an array $watch only fires on the 1st usage:

```
watchedTitlearray: 1
```

and after that my 2nd watch doesn't fire.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Angular 1.2 you should use:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('model.titlearray', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    // ...
});
```

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope)

Answer (score 6):

In order to watch the change of elements in a list, set the 3rd parameter of `$watch` to `true`

```
$scope.$watch('model.titlearray', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    // ...
}, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

As sza said, you need to set the 3rd parameter of $watch to true. This is so that you can compare the two objects for equality rather than by reference, as stated in the [angular scope docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope)

```
$watch(watchExpression, listener, objectEquality)
```

- objectEquality (optional) - Boolean - Compare object for equality rather than for reference.

I fixed your jsfiddle so that it works the way you intended to, here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/r4zce/